# PrimeNG : How to display simple dialog programmatically

Tags: primeng, primeng-dialog

I'm using PrimeNG and I want to display a modal dialog programmatically. I understand I should use the `DialogService` for this purpose. However its first argument expects a Component. This is practical when we want to create a complex dialog with dynamic content inside its body.

However I just want to display a simple text message like this

```
this._dialogService.open(`blah`, { header: 'some header' })
```

How can this be achieved with primeNG?

Comment: What if you try `this._dialogService.open(null, { header: 'some header' })`?

Comment: but I need to display some  text in the body of the modal, not just a header.

Comment: If you need a body, you have to create a very basic custom component which you can reuse everywhere you need it.

Comment: well, that's what I figured. But it is really overkill and I'd be surprised if there is no way to open a dialog with a simple text message. They provide this feature with dialogs that are opened from a button click for example, but I don't see how to replicate this programmatically